# Plot timestamp on x-axis from CSV file

Tags: octave

I'm trying to make a plot with datetimes on the x-axis in Octave. Datetime is a timestamp in "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM" format. I used scan2cell function to read from CSV file, data are printed in array but cannot be plotted - It shows error: plot: no data to plot

```
%code:
filename = 'Test_12.csv';
data = csv2cell(filename);
time = data (:,2);
y = data (:,3);
plot(time,y)
```

Note: CSVread function prints datetime in imaginary format!
2021 -    3i
2021 -    3i
2021 -    3i

Comment: can you post a few lines of your csv file as an example?

Comment: No Time timeToFix
1 2021-03-09 20:02 51
2 2021-03-09 20:14 87
3 2021-03-09 20:16 82
4 2000-01-01 0:03 44
5 2021-03-09 20:21 34
6 2021-03-09 20:31 34
7 2021-03-09 20:41 48
8 2021-03-09 20:51 42

Comment: No,Time,timeToFix
1,2021-03-09 20:02,51
2,2021-03-09 20:14,87
3,2021-03-09 20:16,82
4,2000-01-01 0:03,44
5,2021-03-09 20:21,34
6,2021-03-09 20:31,34

Answer (score 0):

Given th following `Test_12.csv` file:

```
No,Time,timeToFix
1,2021-03-09 20:02,51
2,2021-03-09 20:14,87
3,2021-03-09 20:16,82
4,2000-01-01 0:03,44
5,2021-03-09 20:21,34
6,2021-03-09 20:31,34
```

You can do the following:

```
  pkg load io   % provides the `csv2cell` function

  Filename    = 'Test_12.csv';
  CsvContents = csv2cell( Filename );
  Headers     = CsvContents(1    , :);  % First row contains headers
  Data        = CsvContents(2:end, :);  % Followed by data

% Convert values in cells to desired array format in each case
  Time        = cellfun( @(s) datenum( s, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM' ), Data(:,2) );
  TimeToFix   = cell2mat( Data(:,3) );

% Plot
  P = plot( Time, TimeToFix, 'o' );

% Touch up plot a tiny bit to make it look nicer
  set( P, 'markerfacecolor', [1,0.5,0.5], 'markeredgecolor', [0.5,0.25,0.25], 'linewidth', 2, 'markersize', 10 )
  grid on
  datetick( 'yyyy-mm-dd' )   % Convert 'datenum' values back to appropriate datestrings
  set( gca, 'color', [0.8,0.8,0.8], 'gridcolor', 'w', 'gridlinestyle', ':', 'gridalpha', 1 )
```

[image]